# subset of a topological space is closed if and only if it contains all of its limit points.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, metric-spaces

I'm trying to prove the following:

> Show that a subset of a topological space is closed if and only if it
>   contains all of its limit points.

Is my proof valid?

Definition of limit point:

> $p$ is a limit point of a subset, if every neighborhood of $p$ contains a point in the subset other than $p$ (aka accumulation point).

Lets call the subset, $A$.

In this case we will take $A$ is a closed subset as a given. Lets assume that $p$ is a limit point of $A$, and $p \notin A$. Thus $p \in   \partial A $ because only at the boundary can a point, not in the set, have every neighborhood with points that ARE in the set.(More specifically, because EVERY neighborhood of $p$ intersects $A$.) However, we are given that $A$ is closed and closed sets contain all their boundary points. Thus, $p$ cannot exist (RAA). So if a subset is closed it must contain all of its limit points.

Now the converse. In this case we will take $A$ contains all of its limit points as a given. Lets assume that $A$ is not closed, and thus does not contain all of its boundary points. Let $b$ be a point such that, $b \in \partial A$ and $b \notin A$. However $b$ must be a limit point, because every neighborhood of a boundary point contains a point in A.  Thus $A$ does not contain all of it limit points (RAA). So, if a subset contains all of its limits points it must be closed.

QED

Comment: Clarify please: RAA?

Comment: RAA, stands for reductio ad absurdum, which is proof by contradiction. It is a very common way to prove things. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reductio_ad_absurdum

Comment: Careful with your wording.  In the 1st part of your proof , if $p$ is a limit point of $A$ and $p\not \in A$ then $p\in \partial A $ but NOT because if has a nbhd intersecting $A$, but rather because EVERY nbhd of $p$ intersects $A$.... BTW,  which def'n of "closed" are you using?

Comment: You say in the next to last sentence "However b must be a limit point, because points on the boundary have a neighborhood with points in A." What you mean is that every neighborhood of a boundary point contains a point in A.

Comment: @ user254665, I just did an edit and added "EVERY". My book defines a closed set a one who complement is open. But right before this proof, it give 3 other "equivalent" definitions. One being "closed sets contain all their boundary points"

Comment: @MichaelMaliszesky I'm very familiar with proof by contradiction,but I'd forgotten about that Latin term for it which I'd learned in mathematical logic.

Comment: @ John Wayland Bales, I just made that fix too. When I said neighborhood, I meant for any $\varepsilon$ > 0, $B_{\varepsilon}(x)$ will contain point in $A$. But the phrasing was very clumsy. I guess I need to be sure to use the word "EVERY" when I talk about neighborhoods. THANK YOU.

Comment: @Mathemagician1234, The books I've been using usually write "RAA" right after the contradiction has been made, indicating that the false assumption is not longer needed. I guess I shouldn't assume the "RAA" and "QED" are not common knowledge. I just use them like a punctuation marks at the end.

Comment: @MichaelMaliszesky QED is a phrase I'm quite familiar with as well-my friend,undergraduate mentor and the graduate advisor at my undergrad school,Nick Metas,used it often. : )

Comment: " because only at the boundary can a point, not in the set, have a neighborhood with points that ARE in the set."  Not true. Let A = [0,1] let x = 1.1.  The neighborhood (.9,1.3) has many points in A

Comment: @ fleablood, when i said neighborhood,  i mean an infinitesimaly small one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your corrected proof is correct. Here's a shorter and simpler way to prove the second direction: Let X be the topological space where $A\subseteq X$.Recall that the closure of a set $\bar A$ =$A\cup A'$ where A'= { x | x is an accumulation point of $A\subseteq X$.Recall also that $\bar A$ is a closed set because it is the intersection of all the closed subsets of X that contain A as a subset and the intersection of any number of closed sets is closed. So assume $A\subseteq X$ contains all it's accumulation points. Then $A'\subseteq A$.Then $A\cup A'\subseteq A$.But $A\subseteq A\cup A'$. Therefore, $A = A\cup A'$=$\bar A$ and therefore A is closed! Q.E.D.

In closing, here's one for you to mull your mind over: Consider $A\subseteq X$ where X is a topological space. Assume A has no limit points. Then is it closed? Why or why not?

Comment: An examples of a set with no limit points would be a discreet set, and thus BOTH open and closed.

Comment: @MichaelMaliszesky My question was somewhat misleading,I'm sorry. I wanted to ask merely if the set was closed-it may ALSO be open,but that wasn't the question's intent. I fixed it-it should be clearer now. Your comment above is quite correct. But my question was really why is a set with no limit points closed?The answer's very simple when you think about it,try it.

Comment: Boy, was that a beautiful, easy-to-follow proof! Sometimes textbooks make it so hard, I tell you...